# What is the significance of calling a surname a 'second name'?

Tags: british-english, class-based-usage

I'm reading Agatha Raisin stories--set in the 1990s in the Cotswolds--and the vicar's wife consistently says that the ladies in their society refer to each other by their "second name" [e. g., "Mrs. Raisin"] rather than saying 'surname' or 'last name'.

My assumpton is that this usage tells us something about her social class or regional origin. Am I right, and what is the significance?

Comment: 'Second name' is commonly used here in the UK.

Comment: "Cotswolds" and "vicar's wife" supply both of those already, but @FEA42 is verified by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/second_name).